# How to make a citation with more than 2 authors as "at el." in text, but the full name in the reference list?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

Please, help me with the following issue. How to make a citation with more than 2 authors as "et al." in text, but the full name in the reference list? So far, I use the following code:

```
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
 andothers = {et al.},
 }
 \addbibresource{Reference.bib}
```

Sometimes it uses "et al." in the text, sometime now. In the reference list I have some papers cited as "et al.".

## EDIT:

One bib entry is:

```
@article{banker2016confounding, 
  title={The confounding effect of cost stickiness on conservatism estimates},
  author={Banker, Rajiv D and Basu, Sudipta and Byzalov, Dmitri and Chen, Janice YS}, 
  journal={Journal of Accounting and Economics}, 
  volume={61}, 
  number={1}, 
  pages={203--220}, 
  year={2016}, 
  publisher={Elsevier},
}
```

Comment: The setup looks a bit weird. If you want to use `biblatex-chicago`, you should load it via the wrapper package, i.e. `\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}` instead of `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex}`. And in that case you would probably not use `biblatex-apa`'s language files `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`. Other than that it would help greatly if you could show us a few entries you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the styles of the [`biblatex-chicago` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) you should load it using its wrapper package and not via `biblatex` directly.

When you use the wrapper package to load the `authordate` style, `biblatex` is called with options equivalent to

```
maxbibnames  = 10, minbibnames  = 7
maxcitenames =  3, mincitenames = 1
```

So that you get

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,companion,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations "Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Nussbaum 1978; Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin 1994; Aksın et al. 2006" in the bibliography all names are shown.]

Without the wrapper package the default settings are equivalent to

```
maxbibnames  = 3, minbibnames  = 1
maxcitenames = 3, mincitenames = 1
```

which explains why your four-author work becomes "et al." in both the citation and the bibliography.

To absolutely make sure you get to see all authors in the bibliography, you can increase `maxbibnames` to `999` or some other very large number. If you want a three author work to be cited as *Elk et al. 1980* you can set `maxcitenames=2`, with `maxcitenames=3` they will be shown as *Elk, Hacker and Appleby 1980*.

```
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, natbib,
  maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex-chicago}
```

The `DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}` should not be needed for `biblatex-chicago`, it was only needed in older versions of `biblatex-apa`.